# Uploading pdf newsletters

Tags: files

How would I upload a pdf and link it to a post on my homepage? Basically the PDF is a newsletter and every week I want to upload a pdf (newsletter) and have a link as a story on the home page. I'm using Drupal 7, is this possible? does a module exist for it?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a new module as this functionality is built into core.  Go to (yoursite)/admin/structure/types and click "manage fields" for the content type you want to add your pdf's to.  Add a new field whose field type is "File".

[Working with files in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/file)